# sqlite3_exec == SQLITE_OK failure

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I'm new to developing in objective C and am struggling to step into an IF statement (sqlite3_exec==SQLITE_OK). I have been using tutorials and dont seem to be able to find my answer.

Is anyone able to show me where I'm going wrong?

```
-(IBAction)addItemButton:(id)sender {
    char *error;

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPathString UTF8String], &itemDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *insertStat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO ITEMS(ITEM) values ('%s')", [self.itemField.text UTF8String]];

        const char *insert_stat = [insertStat UTF8String];


        if (sqlite3_exec(itemDB, insert_stat, NULL, NULL, &error)== SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"Item Added");

            Item *item = [[Item alloc]init];

            [item setItem:self.itemField.text];

            [arrayOfItem addObject:item];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Item not added");
        }

        sqlite3_close(itemDB);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to insert a row in SQLlite?

Comment: See https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb. This is a great framework for sqlite on iOS/MAC OS X. You can find the answer in its code

Comment: Also log what [sqlite3_errmsg](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html) returns.

Comment: hi user2071152 yes I am but it doesn't step into that section of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a simple SQLite helper for performing general database tasks with few lines of code like fetching records from DB, Inserting, Updating and Deleting records.
[Source code can be found here with example](https://github.com/mzeeshanid/ZeeSQLiteHelper)

Download and Drag, drop the ZeeSQLiteHelper classes in your project and set your DB name in ZeeSQLiteHelper class.

**Getting records example:**

```
[ZeeSQLiteHelper initializeSQLiteDB];
NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM recipes";
NSMutableArray *results = [ZeeSQLiteHelper readQueryFromDB:query];
[ZeeSQLiteHelper closeDatabase];
```

**For insertion**

```
[ZeeSQLiteHelper initializeSQLiteDB];
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@ (%@,%@) VALUES ('%@','%@')",downloadsTblName, tblAttrFileName, tblAttrFileURL, downloadInfo.fileName, downloadInfo.fileURL];
[ZeeSQLiteHelper executeQuery:queryString];
[ZeeSQLiteHelper closeDatabase];
```

**For Updation**

```
[ZeeSQLiteHelper initializeSQLiteDB];
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE %@ SET %@='%@' WHERE %@='%@'",downloadsTblName, tblAttrFileName, newFilePath.lastPathComponent, tblAttrFileName,oldFilePath.lastPathComponent];
[ZeeSQLiteHelper executeQuery:queryString];
[ZeeSQLiteHelper closeDatabase];
```

**For Deletion**

```
[ZeeSQLiteHelper initializeSQLiteDB];
NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM %@ WHERE %@='%@'",downloadsTblName, tblAttrFileName,downloadedFileObj.videoTitle];
[ZeeSQLiteHelper executeQuery:queryString];
[ZeeSQLiteHelper closeDatabase];
```

Appropriate message of success or failure will be logged on console.